# What should I be aware of when renting a home to a corporation instead of an individual?

Tags: united-states, rental-property

A prospective tenant requested a corporate rental lease on a single family home in Arizona. He plans to live there. Is there anything I should know about renting to a corporation instead of an individual, or is this business as usual in the rental arena?

Answer (score 6):

This is business as usual, except that you need to keep in mind that the corporate entity is separate from the individual. As such - all the background checks and references should be with regards to the actual renter - the corporation.

You should be cautious as it is not so easy to dissolve an individual (well... Not as easy, and certainly not as legal), as it is to dissolve the corporation. So you may end up with a tenant who doesn't pay *and doesn't have to pay* because the actual renter, the corporation, no longer exists.

So check the corporation background - age, credit worthiness, tax returns/business activity, judgements against, etc etc, as you would do for an individual.

Comment: +1 Also, a corporation may have more reason to want to end the lease early if the tenant's work situation changes, so be sure to carefully address the portions of the lease that spell out early termination.